# How to enable Button control when TextBox control has some value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I do not understand why this is not working. The  code is supposed to enable the `Button1` if the `textbox1` and `textbox2` both contains some text but it does not work. Nothing happen after I type some text in both `textbox`es. The `Button1` stays disabled. I even tried both operators || and &&.

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox1.Text == string.Empty || TextBox2.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        Button1.Enabled = false;
    }

    else
    {
        Button1.Enabled = true;
    }
}

protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox1.Text == string.Empty || TextBox2.Text== string.Empty)
    {
        Button1.Enabled = false;
    }

    else
    {
        Button1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

The above code is supposed to enable the `Button1` if the `textbox1` and `textbox` both contains some text but it does not work.

Comment: Did you set `AutoPostBack="true"` to both `TextBox1` and `TextBox2`?

Comment: @ekad I didn't. Now that I have set the textbox on AutopostBack= true it is working. Thanks a lot. Please post it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set `AutoPostBack="true"` to both `TextBox1` and `TextBox2`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBox2_TextChanged" />
```